# Join command making trouble

Tags: join

I have joined two files with the following command.

```
join -j 1 <(sort f1.csv) <(sort f2.csv) > f3.csv
```

After joining I tried to cut two fields from f3.csv.

```
cat f3.csv | cut -f2,10
```

But it can't cut the specific fields rather printing the whole table. I edited the header line for both f1 and f2 by using sed command before joining them to create f3.csv.

```
sed 1d | sed '1i a\t\b........."
```

Both f1 and f2 are absolutely Ok. cut command works for both of them but can't work for my f3.csv. Any solution?

Comment: I suppose this is [tag:bash]?

Comment: yes. In bash. I think after joining the file behavior is changed. All of the columns merge into one column. I opened it in excel and also in R.

Comment: Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS What does "can't cut the specific fields rather printing the whole table" mean? What does "command works for both of them but can't work for my f3.csv" mean? Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use your cut command with -d option worked for me, for example if you are working with space as delim then

```
cat f3.csv | cut -d "" -f2,10
```